# Date format code for MM/DD

Tags: sql

I would like to send the date format from the database as Month/Day only.  I've already stored the date in a table, now I want to send it like this format.  The SQL I have is:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(15),date,102) AS date
```

Which sends MM/DD/YYYY.  My question is what is the code to send MM/DD only?

Comment: Month/Day is not a date.....

Comment: which rdbms r u using?

Comment: I am a fresher.i dont know abt rdbms

Comment: @Thiru in which tool/language u r using this?

Comment: This is `sql_server` ? try using `select substring('MM/DD/YYYY',1,5)`

Comment: @Thiru Do you know if you're using SQL Server, Oracle, or other?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT convert(varchar,DATEPART(mm,date_column)) + '/' +
       convert(varchar,DATEPART(dd,date_column)) from your_table
```

[SQL Fiddle Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6787f/7)